# How to read JSON file from cypress project?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I've started with cypress automation and I'm struggling with JSON files.

Anyone knows how may I read a JSON file, let's say, located in ../example/vehicle.json?

I know cypress is JavaScript, but I'm also having trouble when importing JQuery in cypress project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never worked with Cypress, on checking out the documentation this is something that I think could help you out

```
cy.fixture(filePath)
cy.fixture(filePath, encoding)
cy.fixture(filePath, options)
cy.fixture(filePath, encoding, options)
```

Please check out https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture.html#Syntax

Comment: Thank you. It's not exactly what I was looking for, but I can make it with that

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, this would be the "Cypress" way to access data stored in a json file.

ref: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture.html#Accessing-Fixture-Data

```
cy.fixture('user').then((user)  => {
    var name = user.name
    var pass = user.password
})
```

Where 'user' is /fixtures/user.json

```
{
    "name": "username",
    "password": "password1234"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Hey Cypress geek I have success to use it

```
cy.fixture(profile.json).then((user) => {
        // Delay each keypress by 0.1 sec
        cy.get('#username').type(user.email, { delay: 100 }).should('have.value', user.email)
        cy.get('#password').type(user.password)
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

Juste in case this can help anyone, there is a nice way to do this with the following line:

```
cy.readFile('path/to/file.json/txt/yaml')
```

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/readfile.html

Answer (score 0):

You might find this useful with your question and to organize your project.
Let's say you have your input files here:

```
fixtures    
│
└───website
│      orders.json
│      ...
│
└───mobile
       subCancel.json
       ...
```

You can create a support method that returns the name of the folder in which a given json file is:

```
getFolderForJson(jsonName) {
   let value;
   switch (jsonName) {
     case 'subCancel':
       value = 'mobile';
       break;
     case ... //add your custom cases
    }
   return value;
}
```

Put the json reading logic in a command to be reused in your tests:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('readJson', (jsonName) => {
  cy.fixture(jsonName).then(json => {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json)
    );
  });
});
```

And then use your json file properties in your test actions/assertions:

```
let folder = new BasePage().getFolderForJson(jsonName);
cy.readJson(folder + '/' + jsonName + '.json').then((data) => {
   cy.get('selector').type(data.shippingAddress); //use your own json files/properties
}
```

Comment: `switch` is not the ideal way to do this -- that would create a big monster if you have many files. This should not be code driven, but data driven. The call to `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json))` is not needed.

Comment: @trincot what's the best way then? I have near 200 json files and it's not a big deal. How can we make it data driven?

Answer (score -2):

Create a `UserData.json` file in fixtures folder and define your values something like this:

```
{
  "Name": "Ghulam Nabi",
  "Password":"Admin123"
}
```

Now, in your Test File

```
cy.fixture(‘UserData.json’).then((user) => { 

        cy.get(‘#txtUsername’).type(user.Name)
        cy.get(‘#txtPassword’).type(user.Password)

      });
```

**This is just an example. You can Do a lot of things through this method.**

**Courtesy:** https://softans.com/get-user-data-from-json-file-in-cypress/

Comment: Looks like a copy of two other answers.

Comment: And the link is broken

Comment: Link is working